# HASKELL: Add the first x element of a list of lists in an other

Tags: list, haskell, compiler-errors

I'm new in haskell and i want to create a function that take the x first elements of a list of lists and return it.

exemple: [[14, 15, 84], [84, 79, 78], [45, 78, 98], [45, 48, 98]] and i want only the 2 first so my func need to return : [[14, 15, 84], [84, 79, 78]]

```
push :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
push = (:)

generateKluster :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]] 
generateKluster nb_return count (a:as) b
  | nb_return == count = b
  | nb_return < count = (generateKluster x (y + 1) as (push a b))
```

And I've got this error message

```
*Main> 3 0 [[12, 45, 52], [14, 15, 65], [15, 46, 48], [45, 78, 98], [45, 65, 45]] [[]]

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num (t1 -> [[a1]] -> [[a2]] -> t2)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t1 a1 a2 t2.
              (Num (t1 -> [[a1]] -> [[a2]] -> t2), Num a1, Num t1) =>
              t2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call generateKluster in your GHCi.
Like : generateKluster 3 0 [[12, 45, 52], [14, 15, 65], [15, 46, 48], [45, 78, 98], [45, 65, 45]] [[]]